# Can two variables with positive relationship but no Granger causality?

Tags: regression, cointegration, granger-causality

I ran FMOLS and VECM for cointegrating variables in Stata. The results suggest that the two variables have positive and significant relationship (result of FMOLS), but no long or short run Granger causality (result in VECM). Is this possible?

Comment: Can you strengthen this question? By "variable" do you mean time series? Granger causality refers to time series. Also, by "positive relationship" do you mean correlation and if so (since these are time series data) do you mean lagged or cross correlation?

Comment: @AdamO Yes. It is a time series. I mentioned "positive relationship" since the coefficient from the FMOLS was a positive coefficient with significant p-value. And cross correlation.